# TSQL concat in join is very slow

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, concatenation

We have such query:

```
select X.id_x, A.id_a, B.id_b
from X
left join A on 'A|' + A.id_a = X.id_aOrB
left join B on 'B|' + B.id_b = X.id_aOrB
```

X is linked to A or B and id is computed in the join statement.

- X: 8 000 rows
- A: 36 000 rows
- B: 3 000 rows

This query is very slow, like 10 seconds. No index on `X.id_aOrb`.

Then using 2 "join" tables, updated by trigger, we don't need to concat `'A|' + id` and `'B|'+id`. Results are fetch in less than 1 second. OK.

My question: why is this concat so slow? Is SQL Server no very efficient in '+' when there is too much data?

Comment: Are there indexes on `A.id_a` or `B.id_b`?

Comment: yes. And they are primary keys.

Comment: YOu should not design so that you have to concatenate in joins. It would be better to havea persisted calulated field that does the concatenation on insert and then join to that rather than the plain id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FROM X
LEFT JOIN A on 'A|' + A.id_a = X.id_aOrB
```

is not sargable (SQL Server cannot use an index).

If it uses a nested loops join then it must scan `A` as many times as there are rows in `X`. It is not possible to do an index seek on `A` to evaluate the `'A|' + A.id_a = X.id_aOrB` predicate.

If it uses a merge join it must take a copy of the data and sort it first rather than being able to use the order from the index.

The same of course applies to the join on `B`

Answer (score 0):

Look at the execution plan and see where it spends the most time. Is SQL doing a table scan? They are very slow.  If you don't have an index on X.id_aOrB then this would be a good optimization to do. Some articles on how to interpret execution plans [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/01/22/sql-server-execution-plan-estimated-io-cost-estimated-cpu-cost-no-unit/).

If you are going to run this query a lot, you could create a view from it and index it so that it becomes materialized (maintenance will cost though...)

Comment: Thanks, but we solved this issue. My question is about SQL Server performance when dealing with + and join.

Comment: By the way, I didn't know that we can create indexed view in 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Is the following query faster?

```
With t as
(
  select id_x,SUBSTRING(X.id_aOrB,3,1000) as id_a,null as id_b
  from x
  where X.id_aOrB like 'A|%'
  union all
  select id_x,NULL as id_a,SUBSTRING(X.id_aOrB,3,1000) as id_b
  from x
  where X.id_aOrB like 'B|%'
)
select t.id_x, A.id_a, B.id_b
from t
left join A on A.id_a = t.id_a
left join B on B.id_b = t.id_b
```

Comment: sorry I made a mistake in my left join... `'A|'+` is on the left side.